# Необходимо отсортировать текстовый файл и отделить мужчин от женщин

Tags: c#, сортировка

Есть текстовый файл вида:

```
Иванов Иван Иванович
Иванова Ольга Сергеевна
```

Каждый человек с новой строки,хочу написать программу, которая будет отделять мужчин от женщин и записывать в новые 2 файла. Изучил некоторые методы сортировок, поработал с ними, но только с числами, а как сортировать строки не могу додумать. Кто что подскажет?

Comment: А причем тут сортировка, если вам просто нужно разделять мужские имена от женских?

Comment: То есть вы предлагаете считывать строки текстового файла и обрабатывать их циклом определяя пол?

Comment: Ну, вам же именно это и нужно? `хочу написать программу, которая будет отделять мужчин от женщин и записывать в новые 2 файла`

Comment: Да, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

вот список мужских имен : https://kakzovut.ru/man.html

их надо добавить в текстовый файл или в список в программе ,после этого считываете файл и с данными  `Иванов Иван Иванович / Иванова Ольга Сергеевна` разбиваете строку по пробелам получите :

1. Иванов
2. Иван
3. Иванович

после просматриваете список мужских имен если есть совпадение это мужчина если нету то женина добавляете их в разные списки а потом сохраняете

Comment: Такой вариант (со словарем имен) пригоден для языков где нет отчества и грамматического рода. Для русского языка все значительно проще, скажем, [женские отчества](https://surnameonline.ru/patronymic-female.html) оканчиваются на букву "а", что значительно упрощает задачу...

Comment: @Bulson Вроде в вопросе нигде не указано, что имена в файле могут быть исключительно русскими. В любой мало-мальски реальной задаче наверняка встретятся и -кызы в виде отчества, и люди без отчества...

Comment: @Yaant в вопросе не указано и обратное, и в приведенном примере все имена русские. Хотя для реальной задачи, конечно, ваше замечание действительно актуально.

Comment: На мой взгляд задача не решается на 100%. Как быть с такими женскими именами Наи́ля Вагиф кызы Аске́р-заде́?

Comment: @XelaNimed На Хабре есть статья по этому поводу =) https://habr.com/ru/post/146901/